# Java Web Service Client (Eclipse) doesn't compile but runs

Tags: java, eclipse, web, service, compilation

i'm trying to compile a Java Web Service client with the windows console but there are 100 errors. The client has been made in eclipse, and in it's console it works good. Here it is the code:

```
public static void main (String[] args)throws Exception{
    try{
        MireiaUPMPortTypeProxy proxy = new MireiaUPMPortTypeProxy();
        proxy.setEndpoint("http://138.4.47.33:8087/axis2/services/MireiaUPM.MireiaUPMHttpSoap11Endpoint/");
        String respuesta=proxy.getNER("[content]David is in the office.[/content]", "en");
        System.out.println(respuesta);
    }catch(Exception e3){
        e3.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

When i compile the kind of errors that appear are: *Cannot find symbol* and *org.apache axis.constants does not exist*

Could you help me? i'm new at using web services and i'm so lost. The extrange thing for me is that it runs well in the eclipse console, but it doesn't compile.

Comment: How are executing it in windows cmd? jar? .class ?

Answer (score 0):

it runs in Eclipse simply because dependent libs (jars!) are set in eclipse build path.

to be able to compile from OS console/terminal, you have to set classpath correctly. check eclipse build path (right click on project and look for this menu) and add those dependencies in your console command.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your all related jar files are on class path when compiling your class files.